# SQL Server 2014-Run SQL merge statement in loop/batches for 80M rows

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, merge

Need some help in query optimization for below merge statement. This query takes max time during execution of our process because of number of rows and merge does operation in one shot.
I would like to modify it little bit so I can run it in loop or batch process.

```
    MERGE Target_DB.[dbo].[target_tbl] A
    USING   Source_DB].[DBO].[source_tbl] B
    INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT [IndividualEligibility_IDNO],[Case_NUMB],[MCI_NUMB],[Program_CODE],[Subprogram_CODE],[AGSequence_NUMB],[CategorySequence_NUMB] 
FROM staging_tbl  
where [IndividualEligibility_IDNO] is not null) C
ON C.[Case_NUMB] = B.[CASE_NUM] AND B.[PROGRAM_CD]= C.[Program_CODE] AND B.[SUBPROGRAM_CD]=  C.[Subprogram_CODE] AND B.[AG_SEQ_NUM]= C.[AGSequence_NUMB]AND C.[CategorySequence_NUMB]= B.[CAG_ELIG_SEQ_NUM]AND C.[MCI_NUMB] = B.[MCI_NUM] 
ON (A.[IndividualEligibility_IDNO] = C.[IndividualEligibility_IDNO])
WHEN MATCHED THEN  
UPDATE
SET 
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT
(
)
VALUES
(
);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It would help if you indicated which DBMS you were using with SQL as this would affect the answer. You can add this as a tag by clicking on the [edit] button.

Comment: @BrianTompsett-汤莱恩 -its sql server 2014

Comment: A one shot merge is probably the fastest option. The more work per statement the better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Batching DML will require some type of key or range that can help you with a known batch size - Date, Id, etc.  With that you can add a filter to your merge so it only works with a certain number of records.  Loop that until you've managed all the records and you are good to go.

Pseudo code assuming an identity Key; assuming Case_NUMB from the query above.  Obviously don't know your data, but this will give you an idea.

```
   DECLARE 
      @batchSize=10000
    , @curBatch=0
    , @lastBatch=0
    , @maxRow

   SELECT @maxRow=MAX([Case_NUMB])
   FROM [Source_DB].[DBO].[T0826_AG_IN_GRS_I]


   SET @curBatch+=@batchSize

   WHILE @curBatch < @maxRow
   BEGIN

    MERGE Target_DB.[dbo].[GrossIncomeIndividualEligibility_T] A
       USING   [Source_DB].[DBO].[T0826_AG_IN_GRS_I] B
        INNER JOIN (
            SELECT DISTINCT [IndividualEligibility_IDNO],[Case_NUMB],[MCI_NUMB],[Program_CODE],[Subprogram_CODE],[AGSequence_NUMB],[CategorySequence_NUMB] 
            FROM Staging_DB.dbo.STG_CaseNUM_ID_Holder  
            where [IndividualEligibility_IDNO] is not null
                AND [Case_NUMB] BETWEEN @lastBatch AND @curBatch -->ADD THIS LINE
        ) C ON C.[Case_NUMB] = B.[CASE_NUM] 
            AND B.[PROGRAM_CD]= C.[Program_CODE] 
            AND B.[SUBPROGRAM_CD]=  C.[Subprogram_CODE] 
            AND B.[AG_SEQ_NUM]= C.[AGSequence_NUMB]
            AND C.[CategorySequence_NUMB]= B.[CAG_ELIG_SEQ_NUM]
            AND C.[MCI_NUMB] = B.[MCI_NUM] 
    ON (A.[IndividualEligibility_IDNO] = C.[IndividualEligibility_IDNO])
    WHEN MATCHED THEN  
    UPDATE
        SET 
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
        INSERT
        (
        )
        VALUES
        (
        );

    SET @lastBatch=@curBatch+1              
    SET @curBatch+=@batchSize
   END
```

Comment: Thanks Steve. let me modify my sql merge accordingly. if I see any issue will discus here.

Comment: One thing I forgot to mention is that no matter how you decide to batch, try and make it as "balanced" a batch as possible.  Batching by date isn't a big deal if you have a known and even number of records per date.  But if that data is not evenly distributed across dates, that could be problematic.

Comment: query is running fine but looks like this time it will take longer to process 80M rows.  only thing it wont consume whole tempdb space and wont create logs.

Comment: It's very difficult to troubleshoot performance without knowledge of your system, your indexes, etc.  It would behoove you to take a look at the execution plans and possibly even breaking this out.  Merge operations are very expensive, as I understand them compared to a roll your own set based solution.

Comment: Replace:    `WHILE @curBatch < @maxRow`
With:         `WHILE @lastBatch < @maxRow`